# SQL Query Error: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to query from 2 tables, and calculate a value. I am doing this in inductive automation Ignition using their query tools. Then using that value I want to make 2 calculations.  I eventually figured out I needed a nested query and I believe that I am close but I am getting the error in the title.

```
SELECT

[PalletTally Table 2].PartNumber,

[PalletTally Table 2].ChosenWeight,

[PalletTally Table 2].[Line Speed],

[PalletTally Table 2].PalletCount,

([PalletTally Table 2].[ChosenWeight]*[Part Pallet Info Table].[CUT 
LENGTH]/12*[Part Pallet Info Table].[PIECES PER BALE]+[Part Pallet Info 
Table].[TARE WT]) AS CalcPalletWeight,

(TotalPalletWeight / (1  + (CalcPalletWeight * PalletCount)) * [Line Speed]  
* 12 / 60) AS [Lbs./Hr.]

FROM [PalletTally Table 2]
WHERE 

(

Select




([PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 1 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 2 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 3 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 4 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 5 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 7 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 6 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 8 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 9 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 10 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 11 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 12 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 13 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 14 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 15 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 16 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 17 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 18 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 19 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 20 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 21 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 22 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 23 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 24 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 25 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 26 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 27 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 28 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 30 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 31 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 29 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 32 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 33 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 34 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 35 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 36 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 37 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 39 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 40 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 38 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 41 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 43 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 42 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 44 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 45 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 46 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 47 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 48 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 49 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 50 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 51 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 52 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 53 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 54 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 55 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 56 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 57 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 58 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 59 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 60 Weight] +
[PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 61 Weight]) 

AS PalletWeightTotal

FROM [PalletTally Table 2]
  INNER JOIN [Part Pallet Info Table] ON [Part Pallet Info Table].[PART 
NUMBER]
= [PalletTally Table 2].PartNumber

WHERE [PalletTally Table 2].[Date] > GETDATE() - 5

)
```

I am a total newbie to actually developing SQL (Industrial Engineer who is learning this on the go) so any info that I am totally missing let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your statement says "Select <something> from <somewhere> where <something else>...". A `WHERE` statement must resolve into a `TRUE` or `FALSE` result. For instance: `WHERE a > b`.

Comment: not too familiar with ignition, but with MS's flavor of SQL, you'd be looking for something like `exists` most likely to determine if a record exists within the subquery at the end.  So something like FROM [PalletTally Table 2]
WHERE Exists

(

Select




([PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 1 Weight] +....This may or may not work as-is, thus is why I'm leaving it as a comment...

Comment: Because it's not at all clear what you are trying to get from this SQL (since the WHERE clause is so very very wrong) it may help if you could share some small sample data and your desired results, or an explanation of what you are trying to achieve here with this WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell you the best solution, but - just to answer your question - I'll try to reduce it a bit to make it more obvious:

```
SELECT
[PalletTally Table 2].PartNumber,
--more columns
FROM [PalletTally Table 2]
WHERE 
(
    Select
    (
    [PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 1 Weight] +
    [PalletTally Table 2].[Pallet 2 Weight] +
    --more of them
    ) AS PalletWeightTotal
    FROM [PalletTally Table 2]
    --some joins
    WHERE [PalletTally Table 2].[Date] > GETDATE() - 5
)
```

Basically this means the following

```
SELECT Something
FROM Somewhere
WHERE 
(
    Select ASumOfManyValues
    FROM FromTheSameTable
    WHERE SomeCondition is true
)
??????????
```

You are telling the engine to filter the SELECT. Then you compute a value - and that's it... This value - assumably - should be tested against a border value, something like `>0`.

Hope this helps...

### Hint

I'm pretty sure, that your table design is wrong. Whenever you feel the need to *name-number* elements (something like `pallet1`,`pallet2`) this is a strong pointer to a related side table.

If the table's design is under your control everything would be easier with a proper structure...

Comment: I see what you mean.  To answer your hint first, the table structure was based in Access and is not under my control.           So to accomplish my goal, (calculate the sum of many values and then get two numbers based on that value) In the Access set up there are multiple queries that pull from each other. Is there a way to do that on the SQL side?

Comment: @KSHORC Read about [CREATE VIEW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [common table expressions (cte)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [inline table valued functions](http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/sql-server-inline-table-valued-functions-better-than-a-view/)

Comment: If you can, create normalized views even if the structure you currently have is a little wonky, then query against those in the future.  It will save you a LOT of headaches, and prevent you from having to continue to write queries like this in the future.